# Updating django form without prompting the user to enter their ID

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-users

So i'm working on job application portal.

the logic is as follows :

Applicant ---> Applies for ---> Job

Models are (Job, User, Application)
I used the User model from django and i extend it.
Now the dilemma is when i render the ApplicationForm, because i have to update the foreign key and i want it to be updated automatically.

Here is my code :

Models.py

```
class Job(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='job_owner',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    #location
    job_type = models.CharField(max_length=15,choices=JOB_TYPE)
    description= models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    published_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    vacancy = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    salary = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    experience = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to ='job_icons/',default='job_icons/job.png')
    slug = models.SlugField(blank = True,null=True)





class Application(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, related_name="job_applied",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    applicant = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='job_applicant',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name= models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name= models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60)
    website = models.URLField()
    cv = models.FileField(upload_to='application/')
    coverletter = models.TextField(max_length=550)
    application_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.last_name+"\t"+self.first_name
```

Forms.py

```
class JobApplication(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Application
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name','email', 'website','cv','coverletter']
```

vews.py

```
def job_detail(request,slug):
    job_specific = Job.objects.get(slug=slug)
    form = JobApplication(instance=request.user)


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = JobApplication(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            my_form = form.save(commit=False)
            my_form.job = job_specific

            Application.applicant.user = request.user

            Application.job = job_specific

            my_form.save()



        
    context ={'job_specific':job_specific, 'form':form,}
    return render(request,"job/job_details.html",context)
```

So once the user submit their application, i wanted to updated the fields that are "foreign key" without prompting the user.

I do not know how to arrange this in the views.py or if it's even possible this way?

thanks to everyone in advance

Answer (score 0):

So i solved the problem, it was really simple solution:

```
my_form = form.save(commit=False)
my_form.job = job_specific
my_form.applicant = request.user
```